# Cart quantity update

Tags: input-type-file

So I have been trying to update my product quantity on my cart page but on reload of the page it sets back to the default value of 1

I tried ajax function and I'm expecting it to update in the db without reloading the page

Comment: So you reload the page without reloading the page? You question text is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to keep cart item on browser storage instead of store into db. you can use below approach:

- local storage
- cookie
- session storage.

you can find more detail as [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)